# CakePHP - How to use onError in Model

Tags: cakephp, error-handling

I've created a custom datasource which fetches data from a web api, and I'm now looking at implementing error handling.

In the datasource, I'm calling $model->onError(). In the model, I've created the onError method, and I can access error details with $this->getDataSource()->error;

However I can't redirect or set a flash message because that can only take place in the controller, so what should I be doing here to communicate the error to the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are the errors relevant to fields in your model? If so, use $this->invalidate($field, $message) in Model::onError()

Comment: Thanks.
I've added $this->invalidate(0,$this->getDataSource()->error); into model onError method.
To access it from the controller I'm doing:
if (!$this->Model->validates()) $this->flash($this->Model->validationErrors[0],redirect location..);

Answer (score 0):

I would compile all the errors in the model into a set of errors, perhaps in an array. Then I'd set it as a variable in the Model.

Thus in my controller I can then do `$this->Model->getErrors()` or similar to read and return the value set in the model.

Then in my controller's `beforeFilter()` I'd check to see if there were any errors, and if there were, push them into the flash. `$this->Session->setFlash($this->Model->getErrors(),'default',array('class'=>'error-message'));`